# 3 dimensional arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I am trying to create a 3 dimensional matrix with 400 elements in one dimension and, 4 and 4 in the other two dimensions.

I have crated the array as

```
 clij_the = np.zeros((400,4,4))
```

And then I assign the long 400 vector I have in another file that I have read before to each component of the new array as for example for the [:,0,0] component:

```
clij_the[:,0,0]=[row[0] for row in Cl_the]
```

The problems comes when it reaches

```
clij_the[:,0,4]=[row[3] for row in Cl_the] or
clij_the[:,1,4]=[row[8] for row in Cl_the] or 
clij_the[:,2,4]=[row[11] for row in Cl_the] or 
clij_the[:,3,4]=[row[13] for row in Cl_the] or
clij_the[:,4,4]=[row[14] for row in Cl_the] (or the symmetric ones)
```

with the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "main.py", line 31, in 
> clij_the[:,0,4]=[row[3] for row in Cl_the]
> IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 4

It looks like the hypermatrix clij_the has no 4 index for the the second and third dimensions, but I have defined with 400x4x4 using np.zeros so I am missing something about arrays...any idea?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use index 4 because your array contains only indexes 0 to 3. This logical concept is very basic in programming and specifically in python, the last index of array of size `x` is `x-1`.